# How to Prove that if Any Two Rectangles Intersect, then All Rectangles Intersect

Tags: convex-geometry, combinatorial-geometry

Let $R$ be a collection of closed rectangles in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with sides parallel to the axes. Show that if any two rectangles in $R$ intersect, then all rectangles in $R$ have a common point.

Helly’s theorem requires any $d+1$ rectangles (in this case, 3 rectangles) to have non-empty intersection. However , this question only talks about the intersection of two rectangles as a condition. So, I don’t really know how to go about this.

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you assuming $R$ is a finite collection, or could the collection potentially be infinite?  (Not that it makes any difference to the truth of the statement; but the proof in the finite case could be stated a bit more simply and doesn't need to mention a certain technical detail.)

Comment: @DanielSchepler With the nature of the question, I think it is safe to consider an arbitrary collection of rectangles. In that case, I should have mentioned I thought of **Infinite Helly** , not Helly.

Comment: Hint: take any $3$ rectangles and use the fact that they are parallel to the axes to prove that the three intersect and use Helly theorem

Comment: @Kroki the condition given in the question is “if any two rectangles intersect…”. So, will it be cool if I show that three rectangles intersect?

Comment: Yes you prove that and you use Helly.

Comment: @Kroki I am not sure I know how to prove that three rectangles intersect (given the fact they are parallel to the axes).

Comment: I add an answer for that you can check it if you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $3$ rectangles of $R$, $\left[a_1, b_1\right]\times \left[c_1, d_1\right]$, $\left[a_2, b_2\right]\times \left[c_2, d_2\right]$ and $\left[a_3, b_3\right]\times \left[c_2, d_2\right]$. Since the third rectangle intersects each of the two rectangles then $a_3\le b_1$, $a_3\le b_2$ and also $c_3\le d_1$ and $c_3\le d_2$. Use the same idea for the other rectangles you will have that $\left[a, b\right]\times \left[c, d\right]$ is in all three rectangles, where $a = \max\left\{a_1, a_2, a_3\right\}$, $b = \min\left\{b_1, b_2, b_3\right\}$, $c = \max\left\{c_1, c_2, c_3\right\}$ and $d = \max\left\{d_1, d_2, d_3\right\}$

Answer (score 1):

Let us define four functions $\ell, r, b, t : R \to \mathbb{R}$ which stand for left, right, bottom, top respectively.  i.e. $\ell([a,b]\times[c,d]) = a$, etc.  We then claim that under the given conditions, $\sup_{x \in R} \ell(x) \le \inf_{x\in R} r(x)$ and $\sup_{x\in R} b(x) \le \inf_{x\in R} t(x)$.  Therefore, we will have that $(\sup_{x\in R} \ell(x), \sup_{x\in R} b(x)) \in \bigcap R$.

To show the first inequality, suppose to the contrary that we had $\sup_{x\in R} \ell(x) > \inf_{x\in R} r(x)$.  Then setting $m$ to be the midpoint between these two values, we can find $x \in R$ with $\ell(x) > m$, and we can also find $y \in R$ with $r(y) < m$.  However, since then $r(y) < \ell(x)$, we must have that $x \cap y = \emptyset$, giving a contradiction.  The proof that $\sup_{x\in R} b(x) \le \inf_{x\in R} t(x)$ is similar.

Comment: $(\sup_{x\in R} \ell(x), \sup_{x\in R} b(x)) \in \bigcap R$ does not make sense. You certainly mean $[\sup_{x\in R} \ell(x),\inf_{x\in R} r(x)] \times [\sup_{x\in R} b(x),\inf_{x\in R} t(x)] \subset \bigcap R$ .

Comment: @PaulFrost I don't see what you're trying to say here -- especially given that $(\sup_{x\in R} \ell(x), \sup_{x\in R} b(x)) \in [\sup_{x\in R} \ell(x), \inf_{x\in R} r(x)] \times [\sup_{x\in R} b(x), \inf_{x\in R} t(x)]$.

Comment: I misunderstood $(\sup_{x\in R} \ell(x), \sup_{x\in R} b(x))$ as an open interval ;-)